# help need for sql query, select latest 5 lists of each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL, I have a database table with items and 5 categories(also one ID field, autoincr,PK) I have to  select latest 5 items of each category, when I use group by it return latest one item of each category, how can I get top 5 items of each category in a single query ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You properly going to hate this ...

```
(select * from items where category_id=1 order by add_date desc limit 5)
union
(select * from items where category_id=2 order by add_date desc limit 5)
union
(select * from items where category_id=3 order by add_date desc limit 5)
union
(select * from items where category_id=4 order by add_date desc limit 5)
union
(select * from items where category_id=5 order by add_date desc limit 5);
```

Comment: I know this, but any thing better than this ??

Comment: I guess break down in 5 smaller query? (not sure you prefer that) OR wrap as stored procedure?