# Need to select 5 latest records order by category?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select the five latest products of each brand category, then display those results grouped by the category.

MySQL database looks like;

Table `product` :

```
product_id (pk) 
product_name 
product_etc 
product_publish_date 
brand_id (fk)
```

Table `brand`

```
brand_id (pk) 
brand_name
```

Results should come out like the following...

```
brand_a product k
brand_a product a
brand_a product h
brand_a product l
brand_a product 33

brand_b product h
brand_b product z
brand_b product 9
brand_b product ddd
brand_b product a
```

Tried with

Comment: SELECT * FROM product
GROUP BY brand_id
ORDER BY product_publish_date
LIMIT 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category)

Comment: what problem are you getting ?

Comment: My query only returned 5 results (limit 5), I originally tried to do a bunch of queries like above but joining them / union but i must have had too many syntax errors and in the end I thought it would probably be a poor way (performance) to achieve my aim.

Comment: I used this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666727/help-need-for-sql-query-select-latest-5-lists-of-each-category), there is 10 categories and 50 products per category. This wont be changing often so hopefully it will be enough, even if its not the most eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p1
LEFT OUTER JOIN product p2
  ON (p1.brand_id = p2.brand_id AND p1.product_id < p2.product_id)
GROUP BY p1.item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
ORDER BY brand_id, product_publish_date;
```

As bill karwin said, it's the same problem as in his link - my answer is just an adaptation of that answer to your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
select brand_name, product_name, count(*)
from brand
INNER JOIN product on brand.brand_id = product.brand_id
order by product_publish_date
group by brand_name, product_name
having count(*) <= 5
```